# How to set colors (Not Randomly) to pie chart's each slice in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

How to set colors (Not Randomly) to pie chart's each slice in [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)?

Currently, I found this:

```
    PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yVals1, "Election Results");
    dataSet.setSliceSpace(2f);
    dataSet.setSelectionShift(5f);

    // add a lot of colors

    ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.LIBERTY_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.PASTEL_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    colors.add(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());

    dataSet.setColors(colors);
```

Thanks

Comment: I answered this question in another thread. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468918/setting-the-pie-slice-colors-in-mpandroidchart/42654111#42654111

Answer (score 1):

You can choose whatever color you want to add to the list:
For example, if you want 5 colors: red, blue, yellow, green, black:

```
dataSet.setColors(Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.yellow, Color.GREEN, Color.BLACK);
```

You can also add 2 rgb colors (red and brown) like that:

```
dataSet.setColors(Color.rgb(236, 42, 40), Color.rgb(132, 79, 45));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the order of the colors simply goes along with the order you add your `Entries`.

**Meaning**: The first color you add will be the color used for the first `Entry` you added.

Also **[have a look at the documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Colors)**.