# Setting the pie slice colors in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, android-studio, mpandroidchart

I need to define specific hex values for each slice in my pie chart.

I'm following the [wiki](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Colors) but the method doesn't seem to be working for `PieDataSet`

```
PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(entries, "Fuel");
dataSet.setColors(new int[] { R.color.green1, R.color.green2, R.color.green3, R.color.green4 }, Context);
```

These errors are shown:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'green1'

Expression expected  <-- At the 'Context'
```

Is there an alternate way to set the pie slice color? This seems to work for Line charts but not for pie.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41903182/5241933

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found a work around:

```
final int[] MY_COLORS = {Color.rgb(192,0,0), Color.rgb(255,0,0), Color.rgb(255,192,0),Color.rgb(127,127,127), Color.rgb(146,208,80), Color.rgb(0,176,80), Color.rgb(79,129,189)};

ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
for(int c: MY_COLORS) colors.add(c);
        
dataSet.setColors(colors);
```

Comment: Thank works great for me. I just want to know how to set default background color to a piedataset. Like for example if I have to show only 1 data in the piechart, i would want to set color to that 1 data and the rest of the part will have default color.

Answer (score 6):

use `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.green1)` instead of `R.color.green1` if not colors will not shown properly.

example code in **Kotlin :**

```
 val colorFirst = context?.let { ContextCompat.getColor(it, R.color.colorFirst) }
 val colorSecond = context?.let { ContextCompat.getColor(it, R.color.colorSecond) }
 val colorThird = context?.let { ContextCompat.getColor(it, R.color.colorThird) }

 pieDataSet.colors = mutableListOf(colorFirst, colorSecond, colorThird)
```

Answer (score 2):

This way you can use proper color names from colors.xml:

```
    final int[] pieColors = {
            BaseActivity.getAppColor(R.color.blue),
            BaseActivity.getAppColor(R.color.SandyBrown),
            BaseActivity.getAppColor(R.color.silver),
            BaseActivity.getAppColor(R.color.FireBrick),
            BaseActivity.getAppColor(R.color.gray),
            BaseActivity.getAppColor(R.color.DarkMagenta),
            BaseActivity.getAppColor(R.color.olive),
            BaseActivity.getAppColor(R.color.MidnightBlue),
            BaseActivity.getAppColor(R.color.purple),
            BaseActivity.getAppColor(R.color.DeepSkyBlue),
            BaseActivity.getAppColor(R.color.maroon),
            BaseActivity.getAppColor(R.color.HotPink),
            BaseActivity.getAppColor(R.color.teal),
            BaseActivity.getAppColor(R.color.Purple),
            BaseActivity.getAppColor(R.color.green),
            BaseActivity.getAppColor(R.color.MediumSeaGreen)
    };

    ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int color : pieColors) {
        colors.add(color);
    }

    dataSet.setColors(colors);

    ...


public static int getAppColor(int resourceId) {
    Context context = MyApplication.getMyApplicationContext();
    int color;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        color = context.getResources().getColor(resourceId, context.getTheme());
    }
    else {
        //noinspection deprecation
        color = context.getResources().getColor(resourceId);
    }
    return color;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
final int[] MY_COLORS = {
        Color.  rgb(0,255,255),
        Color. rgb(65,105,225)
};

ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();

for(int c: MY_COLORS) colors.add(c);

dataSet.setColors(colors);
```

Comment: final int[] MY_COLORS = {
                Color.  rgb(0,255,255),
                Color. rgb(65,105,225)
        };
        ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int c: MY_COLORS) colors.add(c);

        dataSet.setColors(colors);
      //  dataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS);

       // data.setValueTextSize(13f);
      //  data.setValueTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);

Answer (score 0):

This way you can use colors from your colors.xml file

```
  dataSet.setColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark),
                getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent),
                getResources().getColor(R.color.greenShade),
                getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark),
                getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent),
                getResources().getColor(R.color.greenShade));
```